# How to remove only one or two fields from documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is a very easy question, just having a really bad brain freeze. In my aggregation, I just want to remove the '_id' field by using `$project` but return everything else. However, I'm getting

> $projection requires at least one output field

I would think it's like :

```
db.coll.aggregate( [ { $match .... }, { $project: { _id: 0 }}])
```

Comment: As of Mongo 3.4.9, your code works: the `_id` field is getting removed, leaving everything else in place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to explicitly include fields when using aggregation either via various pipeline operations or via [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). There currently isn't a way to return all fields unless explicitly defined by field name:

```
$project : {
   _id : 0,
   "Name" : 1,
   "Address" : 1
}
```

You can exclude the `_id` using the technique you used and as shown above.

Answer (score 10):

From **v4.2**, you can make use of [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset) aggregate operator to remove single or multiple fields. You can also exclude a field or fields from an embedded document using the dot notation.

To remove a single field:

```
db.coll.aggregate([ { $unset: "_id" } ])
```

To remove multiple fields:

```
db.coll.aggregate([ { $unset: [ "_id", "name" ] } ])
```

To remove embedded fields:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
   { $unset: [ "_id", "author.name" ] }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just with the exact syntax that you wrote in your question.

Example document:
Person

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('6023a13b756e30fec9f77b26'),
  name: 'Pablo',
  lastname: 'Presidente',
}
```

If you do and aggregation, with `$lookup` you can remove, let's say the `_id` field like this:

`db.person.aggregate( [ { task1 }, { ... }, { taskN }, { $project: { _id: 0 }}])`

Also this way you can exclude fields for other related documents to your aggregation; you would do that like this:

`db.person.aggregate( [ { task1 }, { ... }, { taskN }, { $project: { _id: 0, 'otherDocument._id': 0 }}])`

Performance wise I don't know if this is any good, but leaving that aside, this works like a charm!

More info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-from-output-documents

Also, you can use `$unset` but this I haven't tried out.

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#pipe._S_unset):

> **$unset and $project**

> The $unset is an alias for the $project stage that
> removes/excludes fields

If you are doing a simple `find`, is mostly the same, here are the docs with some examples:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-all-but-the-excluded-fields

Hope this is [useful](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#pipe._S_unset), best regards!

PR